# Не работает самописная PHP функция connect()

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

  include "../login.php";

  function connect() {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) ";
    $query .= "VALUES('$username', '$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result) {
      echo mysql_error();
  }
  }

  connect();
?>
```

Comment: Вызов функции connect() должен был быть в другом файле, но я заметил, что вызов функции не работает вовсе

Comment: посмотрите в БД - точно не работает?

Comment: да, выдает ошибку http Error 500

Comment: Содержимое лога ошибок вебсервера в студию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас в функцию разве переданы параметры подключения? Вот эта переменная $connection в mysqli_query у вас сейчас пустая.

Comment: Вообще, она находится в файле login.php, который я включил. Но сейчас проверю

Comment: Если она у вас действительно существует ранее, то сделайте ее передачу в функцию function connect($connection) { ... } B cоответственно при ее вызове connect($connection);

Answer (score 0):

может эта строка

```html
$query .= "VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."')";
```

Comment: К сожалению, нет.

Comment: Сейчас исправил так попробуй

Comment: Спасибо, ребят. Заработало

Comment: так что было-то?

Comment: $connection эта переменная была NULL по другому быть не могло, у нее не глобальная область видимости, а только внутри функции и поскольку она не была инициализирована то она равна NULL